# Heroku is giving me a 503 when trying to open my web app, works on local host

Tags: node.js, express, heroku

I am trying to deploy to heroku but get a 503 even though it runs on localhost. I am curious as to if my server is set up correctly as I am newer to programming. I hope anyone can point me in the correct direction as to where to look or provide a suggestion as I have spent countless hours on google to this point spanning a couple of weeks.

My main question is if I have set up my server correctly? I am not sure my listener will work for heroku and my .get are used for debugging on localhost when it was initially set up.

Also my full project is available here:

https://github.com/dirkdir/DerekDevSite

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');


app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));


app.get('/json', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET the json");
    res
        .status(200)
        .json( {"jsonData" : true} );
});

app.get('/file', function(req, res) {
    console.log("GET the file");
    res
        .status(200)
        .sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'app.js'));
});



    var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000), function() {
        var port = server.address().port;
        console.log("Express is working on port " + port);
});
```

Logs:

2017-04-24T20:04:43.755866+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module._compile (module.js:542:28)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755867+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755868+00:00 app[web.1]:     at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755869+00:00 app[web.1]:     at Module.runMain (module.js:604:10)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755870+00:00 app[web.1]:     at run (bootstrap_node.js:393:7)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.755871+00:00 app[web.1]:     at startup (bootstrap_node.js:150:9)
2017-04-24T20:04:43.846556+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2017-04-24T20:26:31.826133+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=derekdyerdev.herokuapp.com request_id=609ef253-0a56-41ac-b877-1fb242f6f4e1 fwd="69.36.89.218" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2017-04-24T20:26:32.319732+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=derekdyerdev.herokuapp.com request_id=f2a34e62-9765-

Comment: look at/share your heroku logs. then you'll have more insight to what the problem might be

Comment: Can you run `heroku logs --tail` and paste the result here?
_(this will return recently logged errors, and will probably indicate what is going wrong)_

Comment: Lissy, thank you for your response. I am currently in the office and cannot run the above command, however, I have posted my logs in the question body at the bottom

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have the bracket on line `34` of your `app.js` file in the wrong place.
Since the function is a callback, it needs to be within the params.

Change that last block to this:

```js
const server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 5000, () => {
  const port = server.address().port;
  console.log(`Express is working on port ${port}`);
});
```

I also modified  the `Procfile` to just this:

```
web: node app.js
```

After I modified that I was able to run locally, and I deployed it to my Heroku just to test, and it works fine :)

Comment: Here's a demo of it on my Heroku: https://nameless-beach-38136.herokuapp.com/ (don't worry, I'm taking it down as soon as you've seen it!) It's looking good though!

Comment: I had the default port value to 3000 and that's why it wasn't working, I changed to that 5000 and it worked

Answer (score 3):

This may be helpful to someone.
My initial Profile content was this :

```
web : node server.js
```

and after changing it to this, it worked :

```
web:node server.js
```

The space between 'web' and ':' symbol was the problem. Weird though

Answer (score 2):

I had a similar issue.  Worked on localhost.. not when deployed to Heroku.  My problem?  I had cloned a project (node_modules too) and my package.json did not have express, minimist etc.. so it obviously failed.

**Tip:**  When deploying, view the logs right away so you can see what's happening throughout the deployment process.  Viewing the logs after it has failed will only show you the end of the logs...

Lastly, ensure you listen on the proper port.  I do this (as others do too)

```
var serverPort = 8080;
. . .
var port = process.env.PORT || serverPort;
```

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same error on my heroku app.
I installed cors locally and pushed only the file app.js to the repository and deployed it to heroku.
The error was actually that the cors package wasnt declared on my package.json (I only pushed app.js to github) so when heroku tried to call the app it caused an error because cors was undefined.

The point is, also check if the package.json is updated.

Answer (score 1):

This Might help others

1. From Terminal Check out your `Heroku` Logs
2. Check out the error message
3. This might be possible that any npm module you have installed globally
4. Then just install that npm module locally.
5. Commit the updated package.json and package-lock.json file on git.
6. Then run `git push Heroku master`.

Answer (score 1):

I had this same issue when deploying a **Rails 6** API only application to **Heroku**.

I was getting this error when I try accessing the application in a browser:

> Application error

> An error occurred in the application and your page could not be served. If you are the application owner, check your logs for details. You can do this from the Heroku CLI with the command

> heroku logs --tail

**Here's how I fixed it**:

I ran the command below to check the application logs:

```
heroku logs --tail
```

Then I scrolled up within the logs to view logs from when the application server was started. Then I found this error:

```
2020-12-17T12:28:46.973736+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-12-17T12:28:47.017905+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-12-17T12:28:47.028049+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to starting
2020-12-17T12:28:50.252842+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command `bundle exec puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-production}`
2020-12-17T12:28:53.969375+00:00 app[web.1]: Puma starting in single mode...
2020-12-17T12:28:53.969443+00:00 app[web.1]: * Version 4.3.7 (ruby 2.6.6-p146), codename: Mysterious Traveller
2020-12-17T12:28:53.969472+00:00 app[web.1]: * Min threads: 5, max threads: 5
2020-12-17T12:28:53.969505+00:00 app[web.1]: * Environment: production
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565417+00:00 app[web.1]: ! Unable to load application: SyntaxError: /app/app/policies/user_policy.rb:4: duplicated argument name
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565428+00:00 app[web.1]: def initialize(user, user)
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565429+00:00 app[web.1]: ^~~~
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565468+00:00 app[web.1]: bundler: failed to load command: puma (/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.6.0/bin/puma)
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565510+00:00 app[web.1]: SyntaxError: /app/app/policies/user_policy.rb:4: duplicated argument name
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565510+00:00 app[web.1]: def initialize(user, user)
2020-12-17T12:28:57.565511+00:00 app[web.1]: ^~~~
```

I fixed the error in my code which was caused by a **duplicated argument name**, that is `def initialize(user, user)` in my [Pundit gem](https://github.com/varvet/pundit) policies.

In the policies file for **Users** (`app/policies/user_policy.rb`) in my application, I simply renamed:

```
def initialize(user, user)
```

to

```
def initialize(user, user_model)
```

and almost did the renaming at the other places in the `app/policies/user_policy.rb` file that `user, user` was defined to `user, user_model`.

I saved and then pushed it to production and that fixed the issue for me.

That's all.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do a couple of things before I could get my app running, I will list all of them in case it helps anyone.

1.) Make sure you specify the version of node in your package.json file like this

```
"engines": {
   "node": "14.15.1"
 }
```

2.) Make sure you have no errors in your Procfile, the below command worked for me

```
 web: node server.js
```

3.) My server.js file was inside the src folder and that was the root cause for me, I had
to move it out of that folder and then it started working for me

Answer (score 1):

I was struggling with similar problem then noticed quotation marks in my `Procfile`.  When I removed them problem solved.

```
 "web: node index.js" WRONG!
```

It must be without quotes:

```
 web: node index.js CORRECT!
```

Answer (score 0):

I have run app on local environment. In the log I saw "Module can not found 'index.js'" I updated my main js "app.js" to "index.js" and update package.json for main js. Then push my code to Heroku again. it worked.